# Are there any convergence in distribution (weak convergence) theorems related to martingales?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, weak-convergence

I know of the typical martingale convergence theorem, doob convergence theorem etc, but they mostly pertain to a.s. convergence. Are there any theorems that prove a martingale $M_n \rightarrow M$ with distribution? I understand all the a.s. theorems apply for convergence in distribution, but I am after theorems that *only* converge in distribution

Answer (score 0):

The martingale CLT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_central_limit_theorem might be what you are after?